# Two logarithmic R plots in one diagram: Add texture or pattern + Centering the bars at zero

Tags: r, plot, histogram

For the two column data available [here](https://github.com/alisajedi/repo3/blob/master/test.csv), I am plotting two logarithmic y-axis histograms in one diagram in RStudio:

```
data = read.table("C:\\test\\test.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
par( mar=c(3.1, 5.1, 0, 0)) 
hist.x <- hist(data$a, plot = FALSE, breaks=50)
hist.x$counts <- log10(hist.x$counts + 1)
plot(hist.x, col = rgb(0, 0, 1, 0.99), main="", xlab="", ylab="", yaxt="n")
yAxesTitles=c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000)
axis(2, at=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),labels=yAxesTitles, col.axis="black", las=2)
mtext(side = 3, text = "a vs b", line = 0, cex=1.3)
mtext(side = 1, text = "Number", line = 2)
mtext(side = 2, text = "Frequency", line = 4)
# Adding the second diagram to the first one:
relocatedData=data$b+0.2
hist.y <- hist(relocatedData, plot = FALSE, breaks=50)
hist.y$counts <- log10(hist.y$counts + 1)
plot(hist.y, col = rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.99), main="", xlab="", ylab="", yaxt="n", add=TRUE)
legend(7.5, 4, c("a", "b"), lwd=c(1, 1), col=c(rgb(0, 0, 1, 0.99), rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.99)), pch = c(15, 15), pt.cex=2)
```

And this is what I have till now:
[image]

Now, there are two problems in this plot:

> 1- I want to add texture to the red bars (or two different patterns
> for red and blue). I tried the regular texture solutions but couldn't successfully apply them in my specific diagram.
>
> 2- The space between the first bars (at 0) and the next bars (at 1) is less than other spaces (e.g., between 1 and 2, between 2 and 3 and so on). It seems that it automatically centered any two bars at each of the ticks except at 0 (which it puts both to the right side of zero).

Any solutions?

Comment: I cannot recreate your plot but for your first question, have you tried adding the `density` argument? For example `plot(hist.y, col = "red", density = 5, angle = 45, ...)` should do the trick - here `...` represents the rest of your options.

Comment: Also try running your code with
`set.seed(3)` 
`data <- data.frame(a = rpois(1e4,1),b = rpois(1e4,1))`
versus `set.seed(1)`. I get completely different bar widths.

Comment: @Therkel, thanks for the comments. I could apply the first one (although I tried density before, but now I found that I need col="red" instead of col=rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.99); in other words, the rgb() doesn't work with density).